# Including Linux Mint when selling hardware?

Tags: linux-mint

I'm wondering if the GNU License allows me to include the install file of any Linux Mint release as I wish in hardware that I'm profiting from?

Comment: Are you seriously asking the internet for legal advice? I don't know the answer to your question, but I suggest you seek out a lawyer before endangering any business you might have.

Comment: You know lawyers and other legal hobbyists have access to the internet right? And asking here is free, and quick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes!  You just need to follow the terms of the GPL: provide a copy of the license text, and either a copy of the source code, or a written offer to provide the source code on request.  If you're distributing an unmodified copy of the installer, you can probably get away with just a mention of its source (e.g. the license and a link to where you originally downloaded it), but you might want to [contact the Linux Mint development team](http://www.linuxmint.com/contactus.php) to double check.  I'm sure they'll be happy to hear you're including Linux Mint.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it does.  Also, once you show Windows users Linux Mint they are often eager to buy.  We did a used computer sale as a fund-raiser for my work (We had a bunch of old Vista machines that nobody wanted).  Out of 17 machines sold 13 of them were Linux Mint machines and only 4 still had Vista on them.